# Unable to download to DCIM folder android 11 with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android, android-external-storage, android-11

I have my app targeting API 30 with min SDK 21, I have the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in my `Manifest` file and it is granted as well. However, it is a requirement to download an item from our server to the DCIM folder.

A snippet of the code where I am using the `DownloadManager.Request` function to download in DCIM:

```
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
        request.setTitle(title)
        request.setDescription(description)
        request.setMimeType(mimeType)
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM+"/"+myFolderName?:"",
                fileName)
```

This fails with the error message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not one of standard directories:
> DCIM/myFolderName

Answer (score 0):

> > I have the permission  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`.

That is not needed to be able to create files in public DCIM directory.

Every app can create files there.  But it should be image files with extensions like .jpg, .png, .webp, ..

A .pdf file or .doc is not accepted.

Why didn't you tell what kind of files?

> > request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(                 Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM+"/"+myFolderName?:"",                 fileName)

That should be:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), myFolderName?:"", fileName)
```

Comment: Sorry, these are audio files, of type ogg which are in separate nested folders.

Comment: And why no reaction to the answer itself?

Answer (score -1):

It is restricted in Android 11.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage